# schtasks fails with access denied in a script

Tags: powershell

I have a script that I need to run periodically to check on a status of few jobs and alert me if they run longer than 15 minutes. However, I am getting an error using schtasks saying, "Access is denied."

Here is the script:

```
$server = "server.com"
$taskarray = @("Receive Orders","Send Inventory","Send Shippments")     
$maxminutes="0"
$scriptpath = "C:\Path\ToCSVFolder"
$dateyest=(get-date(get-date).AddDays(-1) -format g)

foreach($scheduledtask in $taskarray){

# Send email function

function sendEmail {

$from = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailAddress "email@email.com";

$to = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailAddress "email@email.com";

$mail = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage $from, $to;

$mail.Subject = "Scheduled Task ( $scheduledtask ) on $server has been 
running for longer than $maxminutes minutes.";

$mail.Body = "Scheduled Task ( $scheduledtask ) on $server has been 
running for longer than $maxminutes minutes. Total Runtime for ( 
$scheduledtask ): $datediff .";

# Connect to mail relay

$smtpserver = "smtp"

$smtp = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient ($smtpserver);

# Send Email

$smtp.Send($mail);

}

schtasks /query /s $server /FO CSV /v > 
"$scriptpath\ScheduleTaskMon.csv";

$longrunning = Import-Csv "$scriptpath\ScheduleTaskMon.csv" |

Where-Object {[DateTime]$_."Last Run Time" -gt [DateTime]$dateyest -and 
$_."Status" -eq "Running" -and $_."TaskName" -eq "$scheduledtask"};

if (!$longrunning) { continue }

$datediff=([DateTime]::Now)-([DateTime]$longrunning."Last Run Time")

if (($datediff.TotalMinutes) -gt $maxminutes)

{sendemail};

}
```

This is the error I get:

```
schtasks : ERROR: Access is denied.
At C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\script.ps1:35 char:1
+ schtasks /query /s $server /FO CSV /v > "$scriptpath\ScheduleTaskMon. ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (ERROR: Access is denied.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

Answer (score 1):

That error message is saying the account you are running the script under doesn't have access to query the remote server. I believe you require admin rights on "server.com" to execute that query.

Drop to the command line and paste

```
schtasks /query /s server.com /FO CSV /v > "C:\Path\ToCSVFolder\ScheduleTaskMon.csv"
```

I suspect you'll see the same error.

Comment: Yes I get same response when I run this command schtasks /query /s server.com, but I also get this message when I run this schtasks /query /s server.com directly from the server with Admin account.

Comment: When I just run schtasks /query I do get the response no permission error. When I run it as schtasks /query /s $server I get access denied. I am running this from the server that has the scheduled tasks configured.

Comment: Check your Firewall. If it's on, you'll need the "Remote Scheduled Tasks Management" exceptions, or the equivalent if you're using a 3rd Party Firewall.

Comment: I ran the scrip with elevated privileges and it ran, getting new errors but I will start a new thread about it.